# How to validate text box?

Tags: c#

```
public bool ValidateText(String strName)
{
    try
    {
        // declaring string variable here
        String strpattern;
        // regex pattern setting 
        strpattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9']{20}$";
        // checking for matching with given string here
        Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);
        // returns status here
        return regex.IsMatch(strName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

when i try insert name like q''''''''''''''''' it is returning string value instead of boolean value . plz , let me know wer im going wrong in this particular function ???

I need to validate the text inside the TextBox. In other words the Text inside the TextBox if not matching with the given `pattern` then it should be converted to matching string. This should be checked for every user entered character or if the user pasted collection of characters.

Comment: Please post your code in a code block for readability

Comment: please give some description on what your code is doing and what and where you are having difficulty.

Comment: `How to validate text box?` - just call this function with your ` `textBox.Text` and see. `ValidateText(textBox.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
        public bool ValidateText(String strName)
        {
            try
            {
                // declaring string variable here
                String strpattern;
                // regex pattern setting 
                strpattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9']{20}$";
                // checking for matching with given string here
                if (!Regex.Match(strName, strpattern))
                {
                  return false;
                }
                else
                  return true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ////handle exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, im facing problem when i try to insert name like this q'''''''''''''' it is returning string rather boolean value

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch` returns a bool.

Comment: What is the pattern you are trying to validate?  Can you give an example?  Seems like your regex is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your question which does not have any description other than the question title which says

> How to validate text box ?

What I can understand from this and your code is you are trying to validate am input textbox field using a regex pattern right ?

Your code seems to be perfectly written for that matter.

What I think you are not getting it **right** is the regex pattern you are using !

Test you regex using [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) or [this](http://www.regextester.com/).

I also recommend you [read this.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html)